# How to read metadata file in R

Tags: r, metadata, parameters, user-interface

- How to read metadata file parameters( like sun elevation,REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND etc ) from R
- How can end user validate the parameter of metadat file(.mtl)?
- How can I pass specified parameter of the .mtl(metadata file) file to the R package function directly(like sun elevation to the landsat8 refconvS() function)

Comment: have you got a sample metadata file we can play with? Is this from some standard satellite data product?

Comment: yes sir from landsat8

Answer (score 2):

The key to reading the MTL is a combination of the readLines() and grep() functions.

First we read the MTL-file into R:

```
MTL <- readLines(file("LC82180762014032LGN00_MTL.txt", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

From there, we can go in and extract the bits we need using grep():

```
ele <- as.numeric(substr(MTL[grep("SUN_ELEVATION =",MTL)],21,29))
```

This can then be fed to the reflconvS()-function. The only real "challenge" is to correctly set the substr()-parameters, so that it extracts only the numbers from the requested line, but a few tries and you'll get it right.

The grep()-function simply pulls out the first line from the MTL-file which contains search-phrase, in my example `"SUN_ELEVATION ="`. As such, you have to be a bit careful when search, in order to assure that you get the information you need, and not something else.

Comment: in above what is the meaning of passing 21,29 (i mean what these numbers in metafile or they positions of search string)

Comment: @user28536, 21,29 refers to position in the full string that I want to extract using the substr() - substring function. I simply tells R that I want from letter 21 to letter 29 in the string that is something along the lines of: "SUN_ELEVATION = 30.241457". Which means that I only want the numbers part, which I then pass on to the as.numeric() function, to convert into a number.

Comment: when I call MTL [68] position showing "SUN_ELEVATION" what does 21 nd 29

Comment: Usually, the sun elevation position will contain something like "    SUN_ELEVATION = 57.99788515" - meaning, a lot of empty spaces and then the information. 21 and 29 refer to the first part of the string that we extract, and the last. So, we take the letters from 21 to 29, which are the numbers. Then we convert those into a numeric that can be used in the processing.